# How to print letters(DNA) in a format of (0,10,6)

Tags: java

I am struggling with this code here. I want print out dna in java that shows format of (0, 10, 6) which need to pass a until test
instead of looking like this

```
ACAAGATGCC ATTGTCCCCC GGCCTCCTGC TGCTGCTGCT CTCCGGGGCC ACGGCCACCG 
CTGCCCTGCC CCTGGAGGGT GGCCCCACCG GCCGAGACAG CGAGCATATG CAGGAAGCGG 
CAGGAATAAG GAAAAGCAGC CTCCTGACTT TCCTCGCTTG GTGGTTTGAG TGGACCTCCC 
AGGCCAGTGC CGGGCCCCTC ATAGGAGAGG AAGCTCGGGA GGTGGCCAGG CGGCAGGAAG 
GCGCACCCCC CCAGCAATCC GCGCGCCGGG ACAGAATGCC CTGCAGGAAC TTCTTCTGGA 
AGACCTTCTC CTCCTGCAAA TAAAACCTCA CCCATGAATG CTCACGCAAG TTTAATTACA
```

It looks like this
ATTGTCCCCCGGCCTCCTGCTGCTGCTGCTCTCCGGGGCCACGGCCACCGCTGCCCTGCCCCTGGAGGGTGGCCCCACCGGCCGAGACAGCGAGCATATGCAGGAAGCGGCAGGAATAAGGAAAAGCAGCCTCCTGACTTTCCTCGCTTGGTGGTTTGAGTGGACCTCCCAGGCCAGTGCCGGG....

here is my code

```
public String formatInGroups(int index, int basesPerGroup, int groupsPerLine) {
      StringBuilder formattedSequence = new StringBuilder();
      String sequence = sequences.get(index);
      int num = 0;
       
      while(num < sequence.length()) {
         for(int i = 0; i < groupsPerLine; i++) {
            for( int j = 0; j < basesPerGroup; j++) {
               if(num < sequence.length()) {
                  formattedSequence.append(sequence.charAt(num));
                  num++;
               }
            }
                       
               
      
      }
     
        
   }
  return sequence;
}
}
```

Comment: One thing I noticed is that you are return 'sequence' instead of  'formattedSequence.toString()'. You're trying to print the original sequence instead of printing the one that you have formated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, I think you just missed some little things here and there, add a new line break after a certain character count and a space after some groups, and also you were returning the wrong variable.
Here check this code I edited based on yours, I just added some simple stuff and you got the remaining right.

```
public String formatInGroups(int index, int basesPerGroup, 
 int groupsPerLine) {
        // I suppose you have a 'sequences' list somewhere
        sequences.add(dna());
        StringBuilder formattedSequence = new StringBuilder();
        String sequence = sequences.get(index);
        int num = 0;

        while(num < sequence.length()) {
            for( int j = 0; j < basesPerGroup; j++) {
                if(num < sequence.length()) {
                    if (num % (basesPerGroup * groupsPerLine) == 0){
                        formattedSequence.append("\n");
                    }
                    formattedSequence.append(sequence.charAt(num));
                    num++;
                }
            }
            formattedSequence.append(" ");
        }
    return formattedSequence.toString().trim();
}
```

Little things to consider on your next problem:

1 - You were returning your original `sequence` instead of the `formattedSequence.toString()`;

2 - Try to avoid using global variables, you can declare them inside your `for` loop;

3 - Try using better variable names, instead of `num` you could name your variable after something that it is doing, like `charPositionCounter`, it will improve your code readability.

Answer (score 1):

You should append a white space to the `sequence` after a dna sequence is appended (at the end of the inner `for` loop). Also, when a line is full, you should append a new line (\n) character to the `sequence`(at the end of the outer `for` loop).

```
public String formatInGroups(int index, int basesPerGroup, int groupsPerLine) {
    StringBuilder formattedSequence = new StringBuilder();
    String sequence = sequences.get(index);
    int num = 0;
   
    while(num < sequence.length()) {
        for(int i = 0; i < groupsPerLine; i++) {
            for( int j = 0; j < basesPerGroup; j++) {
               if(num < sequence.length()) {
                  formattedSequence.append(sequence.charAt(num));
                  formattedSequence.append(" ");
                  num++;
               }
            }
            formattedSequence.append("\n");     
         }
    }
    return formattedSequence.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I am a bit confuse, would you mind showing it ?

Comment: I edit your code. Could you try it? I hope I did not your question wrong.